# 1D real FFT and IFFT of a 3D array

Tags: c, fftw

I have a 3D array which has a dimension (Nx, Ny, Nz).

I want to apply real FFT and IFFT along z-axis using FFTW3 library.

Here, 'z' is the fastest varying index.

I already write the same functional code with python using

numpy.fft.rfft and numpy.fft.irfft. It works exactly as I expected.

But it was too slow. So I tried to write code with C language.

I tried to compare the result of IFFT(FFT(f)) and f, where f is an arbitrary array.

I used the fft_plan_many_dft_r2c / fft_plan_many_dft_c2r for forward / backward FFT.

Here is my code.

(Compiled in Ubuntu 16.04 with gcc and -lfftw3 -lm options)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fftw3.h>

void rfft_1d_of_3d(int Nx, int Ny, int Nz, double* input, double* output);

int main(){

    double* input;
    double* output;

    int Nx=2, Ny=4, Nz=8;
    int i,j,k,idx;

    input  = (double*) malloc(Nx*Ny*Nz*sizeof(double));
    output = (double*) malloc(Nx*Ny*Nz*sizeof(double));

    for(i=0; i<Nx; i++){
        for(j=0; j<Ny; j++){
            for(k=0; k<Nz; k++){

                idx = k + j*Nz + i*Nz*Ny;
                input[idx] = idx;
                output[idx] = 0.;
            }
        }   
    }   

    rfft_1d_of_3d(Nx, Ny, Nz, input, output);

    for(i=0; i<Nx; i++){
        for(j=0; j<Ny; j++){
            for(k=0; k<Nz; k++){
                idx = k + j*Nz + i*Nz*Ny;
                printf("%f, %f\n", input[idx], output[idx]);
            }
        }
    }   

    return 0;
}

void rfft_1d_of_3d(int Nx, int Ny, int Nz, double* input, double* output){

    int i,j,k,idx;

    // Allocate memory space.
    fftw_complex *FFTz = fftw_alloc_complex(Nx*Ny*(Nz/2+1));

    // Set forward FFTz parameters
    int rankz = 1;
    int nz[] = {Nz};
    const int *inembedz = NULL, *onembedz = NULL;
    int istridez = 1, ostridez = 1;
    int idistz = Nz, odistz= (Nz+2)/2;
    int howmanyz = (Nx*Ny);

    // Setup Forward plans.
    fftw_plan FFTz_for_plan = fftw_plan_many_dft_r2c(rankz, nz, howmanyz, input, inembedz, istridez, idistz, FFTz, onembedz, ostridez, odistz, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    // Set backward FFTz parameters
    int rankbz = 1;
    int nbz[] = {(Nz+2)/2};
    const int *inembedbz = NULL, *onembedbz = NULL;
    int istridebz = 1, ostridebz = 1;
    int idistbz = (Nz+2)/2, odistbz = Nz;
    int howmanybz = (Nx*Ny);

    // Setup Backward plans.
    fftw_plan FFTz_bak_plan = fftw_plan_many_dft_c2r(rankbz, nbz, howmanybz, FFTz, inembedbz, istridebz, idistbz, output, onembedbz, ostridebz, odistbz, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    fftw_execute(FFTz_for_plan);
    fftw_execute(FFTz_bak_plan);
    fftw_free(FFTz);

    return;
}
```

the input and output result is supposed to be the same, but it does not.

The input array was a 3D array (Nx=2, Ny=4, Nz=8),

```
[[[  0.   1.   2.   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.]
  [  8.   9.  10.  11.  12.  13.  14.  15.]
  [ 16.  17.  18.  19.  20.  21.  22.  23.]
  [ 24.  25.  26.  27.  28.  29.  30.  31.]]

 [[ 32.  33.  34.  35.  36.  37.  38.  39.]
  [ 40.  41.  42.  43.  44.  45.  46.  47.]
  [ 48.  49.  50.  51.  52.  53.  54.  55.]
  [ 56.  57.  58.  59.  60.  61.  62.  63.]]]
```

and I flattened it as,

```
[  0.   1.   2.   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.  8.   9.  10.  11.  12.  13.  14.  15. 16.  17.  18.  19.  20.  21.  22.  23. 24.  25.  26.  27.  28.  29.  30.  31. 32.  33.  34.  35.  36.  37.  38.  39. 40.  41.  42.  43.  44.  45.  46.  47. 48.  49.  50.  51.  52.  53.  54.  55. 56.  57.  58.  59.  60.  61.  62.  63.]
```

I expected the output would be the same as the input but the actual result was

```
0.000000, 12.000000
1.000000, 8.929290
2.000000, 28.256139
3.000000, 35.743861
4.000000, 55.070710
5.000000, 0.000000
6.000000, 0.000000
7.000000, 0.000000
8.000000, 76.000000
9.000000, 72.929290
10.000000, 92.256139
11.000000, 99.743861
12.000000, 119.070710
13.000000, 0.000000
14.000000, 0.000000
15.000000, 0.000000
16.000000, 140.000000
17.000000, 136.929290
18.000000, 156.256139
19.000000, 163.743861
20.000000, 183.070710
21.000000, 0.000000
22.000000, 0.000000
23.000000, 0.000000
24.000000, 204.000000
25.000000, 200.929290
26.000000, 220.256139
27.000000, 227.743861
28.000000, 247.070710
29.000000, 0.000000
30.000000, 0.000000
31.000000, 0.000000
32.000000, 268.000000
33.000000, 264.929290
34.000000, 284.256139
35.000000, 291.743861
36.000000, 311.070710
37.000000, 0.000000
38.000000, 0.000000
39.000000, 0.000000
40.000000, 332.000000
41.000000, 328.929290
42.000000, 348.256139
43.000000, 355.743861
44.000000, 375.070710
45.000000, 0.000000
46.000000, 0.000000
47.000000, 0.000000
48.000000, 396.000000
49.000000, 392.929290
50.000000, 412.256139
51.000000, 419.743861
52.000000, 439.070710
53.000000, 0.000000
54.000000, 0.000000
55.000000, 0.000000
56.000000, 460.000000
57.000000, 456.929290
58.000000, 476.256139
59.000000, 483.743861
60.000000, 503.070710
61.000000, 0.000000
62.000000, 0.000000
63.000000, 0.000000
```

The left one is the elements of the input array and the right one is that of the output.

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Have you tried to [debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: It gives me no error messages... Does it give you the errors?

Comment: And how do you call this function? How do you initialize the data you pass to your function? How do you print the result? Please create a [mcve] to show us (hard-coded "input" is fine, it's actually better for testing). Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Okay sorry.. this is my second time to ask questions. I will rewrite my code

Comment: if numpy.fft was too slow try `pip install mkl-fft` -- it makes numpy.fft 5-10x faster (MKL FFT tends to be even faster than FFTW).

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I have to do some other things too so the only option for me is to use C language. Anyway thank you very much

Comment: I reuploaded my code which gives me no errors. Still, the problem is not solved...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `fftw_plan_many_dft_c2r()`: `nbz`, the size of the transform, is to be set to `Nz`, the size of the **real output** array. It is likely similar for `fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d()`.

```
// Set backward FFTz parameters
int rankbz = 1;
int nbz[1] = {(Nz)}; // here !!!
const int *inembedbz = NULL, *onembedbz = NULL;
//int inembedbz[1]={Nz/2+1};
//int onembedbz[1]={Nz};
int istridebz = 1, ostridebz = 1;
int idistbz = (Nz/2+1), odistbz = (Nz);
int howmanybz = (Nx*Ny);

// Setup Backward plans.
fftw_plan FFTz_bak_plan = fftw_plan_many_dft_c2r(rankbz, nbz, howmanybz, FFTz, inembedbz, istridebz, idistbz, output, onembedbz, ostridebz, odistbz, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
```

As the `input` and `output` array are used by FFTW transforms, it is advised to allocate them using `fftw_malloc()` or a similar function, as you did for `FFTz`. These functions ensure that requirements regarding memory alignment are met. See function `*X(kernel_malloc)(size_t n)` in fftw-3.3.6-pl2/kernel/kalloc.c . It calls functions like [`memalign()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memalign) or [`_aligned_malloc()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/aligned-malloc?view=vs-2019) among others. Both these two return `NULL` just like `malloc()` in case of failure.

There is a difference of scale. Indeed, chaining a forward and backward FFTW transforms of length `Nz` results in a scaling by `Nz`.

Fianlly, some FFTW transforms, such as c2r, are allowed to overwrite their input arrays, except if the [flag FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Planner-Flags.html) is added:

> FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT specifies that an out-of-place transform must not change its input array. This is ordinarily the default, except for c2r and hc2r (i.e. complex-to-real) transforms for which FFTW_DESTROY_INPUT is the default. In the latter cases, passing FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT will attempt to use algorithms that do not destroy the input, at the expense of worse performance; for multi-dimensional c2r transforms, however, no input-preserving algorithms are implemented and the planner will return NULL if one is requested.

Comment: Thank you very much! It solves the problem. It is a huge relief... Also, thanks for the kind explanation about FFTW_RESERVE_INPUT.